# Need a Regex for JS to find the word case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

The following words have to be identified `["CO","C/o","co", "O/B", "O/B of", "On/B of","OB", "OnB",]`. I need a regex that checks for the word entirely but shouldn't return true if the input is "company" or anything that partially contains the words list.

I have tried the following regex
`/(^c\/?o$)*(^b\/?o$)*(^on\/?b)/ig`
It works for some cases but is there any other solution in case I have more words to check for and doesnt have to manually write each of the words in future.

Example- "Copenhagen" should be false
"I want a co along with it"  should be true
"Bob will do it"  should be false

The above regex fails for " I want a co with it" .

Comment: Show us what you have tried - SO is not a free coding service, we fix problems, but don't write all the code.

Comment: How strict do you want to be on patterns like `ONB`, `OB of` etc... meaning can there be more alternations that you'd allow and does it have to be case-sensitive?

Answer (score -1):

This is for ["CO","C/o","co"]:

```
/\W*c\/?o\W/gi
```